# New SSD causes screen freezing on an old laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, freeze

My father has a old laptop made by Lenovo. He wants me to replace the original HDD with a SSD so the laptop can run faster. So I bought Samsung 860 EVO 250 GB (SATA) and did replacement.

But after the installation of Windows 10, at the first time entering operating system, the screen froze and Windows didn't respond to any keyboard and mouse input. I think the entire OS was dead because the screen kept on even the lid is closed.

- The laptop itself works fine with old HDD, so it can't be the problem of other parts of laptop.
- I put the SSD on my computer and it worked fine for several hours, so I think the SSD itself is OK.
- To ensure that the freezing is not caused by drivers, I didn't set up anything after the installation finished. I just leave it at intialization guide for about 20 minutes and kept it isolated from the Internet, screen froze again.

It seems that the new SSD “mismatch” with the laptop. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There really shouldn't be a "mismatch". Rather either a botched installation, or more likely leaving it disconnected from the internet was a bad idea, as Windows needs internet to install drivers.

Comment: I know this. I disconnect it from the Internet because I want to make sure that this bug is not caused by other drivers (such as graphics card).  But it will still become unresponsive after the OS installation.

Answer (score 0):

Cheng Luyu,

It might be the cable which connects the disk to the motherboard. I know you said:

> The laptop itself works fine with old HDD, so it can't be the problem of other parts of laptop.

But I had a similar issue earlier this year replacing a coworker's HDD with a new SSD on a MacBook Pro. The original HDD worked fine (albeit slow), but when I installed the SSD the operating system would not even boot. The SSD worked fine in other computers... so I researched and came across many people saying swapping out the SATA cable fixed their problem. Like you, I was skeptical but tried it out anyways. It worked.

If you have a SATA <-> USB cable, you can try to boot from the SSD via USB. Then if that works, you know it's probably the internal SATA cable.

I don't know why a broken SATA cable can work with one hard drive, and not another... but it IS possible.